# Passing a Func without knowing the object instance

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, expression

I have a Class Foo with a number of methods that return DataSet.  I want to be able to pass a `Func<DataSet> process` into a method that can call the requested method on an instance of Foo that the calling method doesn't know.  Something like this:

```
DataSet CommonMethod( Func<DataSet> process )
{
    Foo foo = GetFooFromSomewhere( );
    return foo.process( );  // <-- obviously, not this way!
}
```

called with something like

```
DataSet ds1 = CommonMethod( GetDataSetForX );
DataSet ds2 = CommonMethod( GetDataSetForY );
```

where GetDataSetForX/Y are methods of Foo.

[NOTE:  I don't own Foo - I can't make changes to it.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
DataSet CommonMethod( Func<Foo, DataSet> process )
{
    Foo foo = GetFooFromSomewhere( );
    return process(foo);
}

// call it like this:
DataSet ds1 = CommonMethod(f => f.GetDataSetForX());
DataSet ds2 = CommonMethod(f => f.GetDataSetForY());
```

But honestly, in your simple example, I don't see the benefit. Why not just do it the "old fashioned way"?

```
DataSet ds1 = GetFooFromSomewhere().GetDataSetForX();
DataSet ds2 = GetFooFromSomewhere().GetDataSetForY();
```

Comment: Thanks.  The benefit comes because the example is simplified.  CommonMethod actually has a lot of code I would otherwise duplicate, both before and after the retrieval of the DataSet.